# How to find out how many concurrent connections to WCF service exists?

Tags: .net, wcf

I need to determine how many users are connected to a WCF service. I am using the NetTcpBinding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WCF services includes performance counters that you can track with the [Windows Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) (Perfmon.exe). You can launch this from the Administrative Tools in Windows Server 2003.

Performance counters can be enabled from the diagnostics section of the `.config` file for the service, as shown in the following sample configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" /> 
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

You may want to check out these articles which can guide you on how to use the performance counters for WCF services:

- [MSDN - WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx)
- [MSDN - Using Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750527.aspx)
- [How to use performance counters to diagnose performance of WCF applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2007/09/07/how-to-use-performance-counters-to-diagnose-performance-of-wcf-applications.aspx)
- [Sajay's Blog - WCF Performance Counters](http://www.sajay.com/post/2009/09/13/WCF-Performance-Counters.aspx)

Comment: Is there a performance counter for current number of WCF sessions? Cause that would be the answer to the question and it's not readily obvious in the links.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your service to count the number of live connections you could obtain this number for every binding. But since you specified that you are using the net.tcp binding I think you should use `netstat` or a packet sniffer tool, like Wireshark, for that purpose.

If your server is hosted in IIS, I think it can give some usage statistics.